# first java servet showing blank output screen on browser

Tags: java, servlets

code is below:dateServlet.java

```
package com.love.servlet;
import javax.servlet.*;
 import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import java.io.PrintWriter;

  public class dateServlet extends GenericServlet
  {
  public void service(ServletRequest req,ServletResponse res)throws ServletException,IOException
  {
    PrintWriter pw=null;
    Date date=null;
   res.setContentType("text/html");
    pw=res.getWriter();//get printer object
    date=new Date();get date object
    pw.println("<h1 stype='align:center'date and time is::"+date+"</h1>");
  pw.close();

}
}
```

web .xml file is below:

```
  <web-app>
 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>s1</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>com.love.servlet.dateServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>s1</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

saved in DateApp folder in webapps folder of tomcat

but localhost:5050/DateApp/hello showing blank screen without error
plz tell me where i am wrong

Answer (score 0):

Can you add below line in servlet tag and check if the page loads:

```
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```

Basically that should load your servlet at server startup.

Second point would be to check if your server is running at 5050 port. Normally most http servers run at 8080. Just make sure you are passing correct port.

Comment: as 8080 port is used by other service so i have set 5050 ,above code is not working ,

Comment: Could you start the application in debug mode and put a debug point in your servlet code and see if it hits. It should work.